# sql server 2008 Invalid column index 0

Tags: java, sql-server

```
  results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + database + ".dbo." + tablename);
  ResultSetMetaData metaData = results.getMetaData();

  if (metaData != null) {
        System.out.println(database + ".dbo." + tablename+"ColumnCount()"+metaData.getColumnCount());
            for (int i = 1; i < metaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                columnMap.put(metaData.getColumnName(i), metaData.getColumnTypeName(i));
            }
        }
```

Comment: by using this code, query returning 29 records, but if i use int i = 0 in for loop i am getting importColumnCount()30
Invalid column index 0.

Comment: actual columns are 30 in that table, i need to put them in Map, but one column is missing because of using int i=1 in for loop, Please advise how can i get 30 column names ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because ResultSetMetaData is a 1 based list.

Change your code to be:

```
 results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + database + ".dbo." + tablename);
  ResultSetMetaData metaData = results.getMetaData();

  if (metaData != null) {
        System.out.println(database + ".dbo." + tablename+"ColumnCount()"+metaData.getColumnCount());
            for (int i = 1; i <= metaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                columnMap.put(metaData.getColumnName(i), metaData.getColumnTypeName(i));
            }
        }
```

Here is an example of using the ResultSetMetaData:

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/sql/resultsetmetadata/java-sql-resultsetmetadata-example/

Comment: Thank you Avitus, its working.
 i should use i <= metaData.getColumnCount();